# UnsatissfiedLink Error : Java jar_Sikuli

Tags: java, jar, sikuli, sikuli-script

I have a automation test suite written in java using [Sikuli](https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/) and TestNG. I have created a Jar file for this project. Sikuli requires some `*.dll` to identify screen objects. To load these libraries I have used below code.

```
 public class OmsTest {
        static{

            System.load("D:\\OMS\\bin\\Sikuli-IDE\\libs\\VisionProxy.dll");

            System.load("D:\\OMS\\bin\\Sikuli-IDE\\libs\\Win32Util.dll");

        }
...
}
```

However, it is giving `dependent library not found:Win32Util.dll` when I run the jar file. I tried loading other dependant dlls, they all are getting loaded successfully and belong to same above path. I also have this location stored in PATH variable. But no luck.
 How should I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to `SikuliX 1.1.0` instead of `Sikuli Script X-1.0rc3` as answered on https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/272529.